# Reconnecting an Android app to a paired bluetooth device

Tags: android, bluetooth, broadcastreceiver

I am developing an Android app that connects beautifully to a Bluetooth device. If that device is turned off, the BT connection is lost, understandably. I would like to reconnect with the device when it is turned back on or comes back in range. Is there an intent sent out by the system when it detects a paired BT device that I can catch with a broadcastreceiver or some other way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I dont think there is an automatic way to do that.

However, you can have a [`service`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html) scanning periodically for devices and notifying your application when this specific device is found.